# Getting this error in mijoshop

Tags: plugins, import, export, opencart

I'm using [this plugin](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17) with Mijoshop.

> Unknown column 'cg.name' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT ps.*, cg.name FROM
>   `n6175_mijoshop_product_special` ps LEFT JOIN
>   `n6175_mijoshop_customer_group` cg ON
>   cg.customer_group_id=ps.customer_group_id WHERE ps.product_id BETWEEN
>   24 AND 719 ORDER BY ps.product_id, name, ps.priority

I am getting this error when I want to export data. Been working correctly before, suddenly gives an error.

Kind regards.

Comment: have you try contact from it module support?